# Javascript How to frame an dynamic if condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 6 filters in my table and based on each filter select I need to create an array of object which matches all the filter conditions that are given . currently I tried something like this

```
$scope.exportConditonVariable ===undefined
```

on click of apply button

```
 $scope.apply=function(){
  $scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue1,tableobjname);
$scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue2,tableobjname);
$scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue3,tableobjname);
$scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue4,tableobjname);
$scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue5,tableobjname);
$scope.conditionObjectFraming(filtervalue6,tableobjname);
};
```

The below function will check if the filter value is not undefined and it will push it an string.

```
  $scope.conditionObjectFraming=function(value,obj){
        if(value !=undefined){
          if($scope.exportConditonVariable ===undefined){
            $scope.exportConditonVariable="'"+value+"'===$scope.tableData[i]."+obj;
          }else{
            $scope.exportConditonVariable+=" && '"+value+"'===$scope.tableData[i]."+obj;
          }
        }
      }
```

the problem I have now is when I iterate through the tableData array like below

```
for(var i=0;i<$scope.tableData.length;i++){
        if($scope.exportConditonVariable){
          $scope.exportArray.push($scope.tableData[i]);
        } 
}
```

The if condition is always true because it is considering $scope.exportConditonVariable as a string.How can I achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you have a table of data with 6 columns where each column has a filter that allows you to filter the rows in the table on the chosen value, while allowing multiple filters.

Here's what I generally do in this scenario:

- Create an array of all the data
- Create a second array with just the filtered data
- Create a function that is called whenever the filter change
- In that function, fill the second array with those rows of the first array that match the filter. This filter can then be as complex as you want.

I've included a snippet to illustrate. I hope this helps you on your way.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myController", function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.filter1 = undefined;
    _this.filter2 = undefined;
    _this.filter3 = undefined;

    _this.tableData = [{
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'where'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'where'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'data',
      col3: 'where'
    }, {
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'some',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'where'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'no',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'where'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'here'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'there'
    }, {
      col1: 'much',
      col2: 'unicorns',
      col3: 'where'
    }, ];

    _this.filterChanged = function() {
       _this.filteredTableData = _this.tableData.filter(function(row) {
          if (_this.filter1 && (!row.col1 || row.col1.indexOf(_this.filter1) < 0)) return false;
          if (_this.filter2 && (!row.col2 || row.col2.indexOf(_this.filter2) < 0)) return false;
          if (_this.filter3 && (!row.col3 || row.col3.indexOf(_this.filter3) < 0)) return false;            
          return true;
       });       
    }
    _this.filterChanged();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="myController as vm">

    Example with just 3 columns for brevity:

    <h3>Filters</h3>
    <div>filter col 1:
      <input ng-change="vm.filterChanged()" ng-model="vm.filter1">
    </div>
    <div>filter col 2:
      <input ng-change="vm.filterChanged()" ng-model="vm.filter2">
    </div>
    <div>filter col 3:
      <input ng-change="vm.filterChanged()" ng-model="vm.filter3">
    </div>

    <h3>Table data</h3>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in vm.filteredTableData">
        <td ng-bind="row.col1"></td>
        <td ng-bind="row.col2"></td>
        <td ng-bind="row.col3"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is I am using [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/) plugin and the filter comes by default.The above thing I need to download the filtered result as an excel

Comment: Aha, well if the expression is a string you could try `$scope.$eval(<your string here>)` to evaluate the string. If you do, remember that the expression is evaluated on the scope, so you don't inlcude `$scope.` in the expression. (So `===$scope.tableData[i].` just becomes `===tableData[i].`)